# TERADATA: where are the procedures' bodies stored in DBC

Tags: sql, teradata, database-administration

In TERADATA we use `SHOW PROCEDURE [procedure_name]` to show the procedure definition/body.

where can I query the procedures' bodies in a way similar to querying views definitions from DBC.TABLESV

```
SELECT requesttext FROM dbc.tablesv WHERE tablename=[view_name]
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no way besides `SHOW PROCEDURE`, as the actual source code is not found in any DBC table.

Source and compiled SP are stored internally in a subtable, which can't be accessed directly.

Edit:

There's a Java-XSP from Glenn McCall which returns the result of a SHOW, can be found on Teradata's community site: [Running Unsupported Queries from a Stored Procedure](https://community.teradata.com/t5/Extensibility/Running-Unsupported-Queries-from-a-Stored-Procedure/td-p/35414) You should be able to run this from a cursor in an SP, but it's probably not very efficient.

Comment: Can we use the show procedure statement in a procedure or UDF to return the procedure body?? if yes, how can it be accomplished??